# Osmosis setup on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: ubuntu, linux, osmosis

I have Ubuntu 14.10. 
I've installed osmosis from apt. I downloaded mapfile-writer from here

http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/simple/sonatype-snapshots-cache/org/mapsforge/mapsforge-map-writer/0.4.0-SNAPSHOT/mapsforge-map-writer-0.4.0-20140127.161606-1.jar

I put mapwriter to /usr/bin and /home/.openstreetmap/osmosis/plugins (just in case)

But when I run following command I get an error

```
/usr/bin/osmosis --read-xml file=UA.osm  --mapfile-writer file=dnipropetrovsk.map bbox=47.45,32.94,49.19,36.94 type=hd
```

:

```
SEVERE: Execution aborted. org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: Task type mapfile-writer doesn't exist.
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.TaskManagerFactoryRegister.getInstance(TaskManagerFactoryRegister.java:60)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.Pipeline.buildTasks(Pipeline.java:50)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.Pipeline.prepare(Pipeline.java:112)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.run(Osmosis.java:86)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.main(Osmosis.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:328)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:408)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:351)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:31)
```

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684179/installing-mapsforge-mapwriter-plugin help?

Comment: No. Because In my system there is no $OSMOSIS_HOME variable.

Comment: There is an implicit OSMOSIS_HOME, depending on how it got installed. I don't know which repo you used, but there could be a osmosis-plugins.conf somewhere already. In any case, the osmosis config is somewhere on your system.

Comment: I have installed osmosis by apt.

`~$ apt-cache show osmosis
Package:osmosis
Depends: default-jre-headless|java6-runtime-headless, libcommons-codec-java, libcommons-compress-java (>= 1.4.1), libcommons-dbcp-java, libjpf-java, libmysql-java, libnetty-java, libpostgis-java, libpostgresql-jdbc-java, libspring-beans-java, libspring-context-java, libspring-core-java, libspring-jdbc-java, libspring-transaction-java, libplexus-classworlds-java, libprotobuf-java, libosmpbf-java, libbatik-java, libcommons-pool-java, libxerces2-java, libxz-java
Filename: pool/universe/o/osmosis/osmosis_0.43.1-1_all.deb`

Comment: And I can't find any osmosis-plugins.conf file in my system.
Looks like standard installation of osmosis doesn't have such conf file.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to [your own comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131220/osmosis-setup-on-ubuntu-14-10#comment192975_131220):

as written [here](https://github.com/ncolomer/elasticsearch-osmosis-plugin/wiki/Quick-start#1-install-osmosis), you have to create the $OSMOSIS_HOME/config/osmosis-plugins.conf if necessary.

Comment: I wanted to create it but I don't have $OSMOSIS_HOME after installing osmosis by apt.
Should I reinstall osmosis manually without using apt?

Comment: You have to manually set $OSMOSIS_HOME as a Linux variable, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234742/setting-environment-variables-in-linux-using-bash . In my installation, the value (path of osmosis) is /opt/osmosis-0.43 .

Answer (score 0):

`sudo dpkg -L osmosis` will show you all the files and folder changed by the package installer. See if there is a .conf file created which will be your configuration file and see if there if a folder with lots of .jar files which will be your plugin directory.